# System Settings has two online account icons?

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, settings

I have two Online Accounts icons in System Settings. I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

[image]

Clicking the red one shows me my facebook account, Clicking the blue shows nothing, so I can probably deduce those are different applications.

Is it possible that it's related to my switch from Unity to Gnome-Shell? (No other icon is doubling)

If it is, how/should I remove the Unity version?

Comment: Thanks maggotbrain, I don't have enough rep to post a pic :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug. One is *gnome-online accounts* and the other one is *ubuntu online accounts*. Removing one may affect other installed app.

Comment: It sounds like troubles in the future for me, Should I merge them, if that's possible? (like making gnome-OA refer to ubuntu-OA?)

Comment: No, you can't merge it, they are separate apps, You have to maintain both online accounts because some apps depends ubuntu online accounts and some apps depnds gnome online accounts

Comment: That's a shame.

Comment: This seems like a pretty big oversight from a UX perspective. I was hoping this would be fixed in 13.10. Is there any way to rename them myself? ie. Online Account Integration and Instant Messaging Accounts